# understanding loss function for multiclass classification?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, loss-functions, multi-class

I was reading through Stanford CS229 note and came across this loss function for multiclass classification:

[image]

We have [image]
Given this, I don't really understand how minimizing this loss function would give us the correct answer.

Comment: Could you please explain how do you get to that expression and tell what $theta_{y} $ is?

Comment: I was given this loss function and there is no explanation about it, which is why I am still struggling with it. As for theta y, y is the output so it can take labels from 1,2 ... ,k so theta y is just the parameter for the label (for example, y = 3 => theta y = theta 3)